# How to integrate offline Dictionary with synonyms in android app

Tags: android, dictionary

I want to show word meaning and synonyms (offline) on long press on any word, which means that integrating an offline `Dictionary` with synonyms in my app. Is there any library or some another way to integrate `Dictionary` in app?. I have try using `Database` but it was difficult because there are more than 200k words. Is there any another way?

Comment: Don't know any library is available but what I did was copy all the word-meanings into separate html files a.htm,b.htm...z.htm so and so. Then I used jsoup to get html contents and could easily go to each words.

Comment: but its too much difficult because there are more than 2 lakh word

Comment: That's why I divided each letter into separate file.

Comment: Why actually `Database` is bad idea? You should build proper indexes and everything will be fine.

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks for improvement